# Music equipment used by artists question on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I (misguidely) answered a question about HiFi equipment used to *listen* to music with a reply about instruments used in songs.
[This question](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25/music-equipment-question-on-topic/47?noredirect=1#comment85_47)

> I think that equipment questions are on topic.
>
> For instance, in 'name of song' what intrument created this perculiar sound 5.43 mins into the song ?
>
> I'd draw a line at 'what specific make/model/year [instrument] did [musician] use on [track name]' as this is far too specific and probably should be in the musical performance site...

So, are questions about instruments used by artists on recordings or live permitted?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes! As a fan, I would like to see what bass Charles Mingus used when he played back in the day.

I believe these kind of questions are one of the most characteristic fan questions

Answer (score 6):

I think so, if they are trivia or general interest questions. However, technical questions regarding usage of instruments should be a matter for music.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's the sort of thing music fans want to know. Make and models are appropriate too IMO as without which you are just left with "Fredd Bloggs played a bass" which is pretty useless info because the fans will already *know* he plays a bass. The answer will also be factual and verifiable, not opinion based (unlike several questions that seem to have snuck through in beta.)